# I am using this code to create PDF, works great on my computer, but ha compatibility issues on others. Have you run across this before?

Tags: vba

```
    Sub CreatePWPDF(DefName, PassPhrase)
'Purpose: Sub to create and password protect PDF copy of the raw workbook
'Function: Utilizes the PDFCreator reference library to create and password protect pdf copies of the raw workbook
'Inputs:
'(1) DefName - The name of the file without the file type extension
'(2) The passphrase to encrypt the PDF
'Notes:
'(1) Requires the PDFCreator reference library enabled to work
'(2) Does not work with PDFCreator version 2.0 or greater since it does not appear to have the PDFCreator reference library

Dim pdfobj As PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator
Dim FPath$, KillFile As String

FPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator 'Defines the file path. Ensures that the PDF is saved in the same place as the raw workbook
KillFile = FPath & DefName & ".pdf"


Set pdfobj = New PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator 'Define PDF Object variable

With pdfobj

    If .cStart("/NoProcessingAtStartup") = False Then 'Check to see if PDFCreator is already running.
        MsgBox "Can't initialize PDFCreator. If PDF Creator is already running, close PDFCreator and try again.", vbCritical + _
                vbOKOnly, "Critical Error with PDFCreator"
        Exit Sub 'If PDFCreator is already running then exit sub. This is necessary in order to prevent errors from occuring.
    End If

    .cOption("UseAutosave") = 1 'Allows for automatic saving into a directory
    .cOption("UseAutosaveDirectory") = 1
    .cOption("AutosaveDirectory") = FPath 'Define file path
    .cOption("AutosaveFilename") = DefName 'Define file name
    .cOption("AutosaveFormat") = 0    ' Set format to PDF
    .cOption("PDFUseSecurity") = 1 'Enable password protection
    .cOption("PDFOwnerPass") = 1 'Enable editing password
    .cOption("PDFOwnerPasswordString") = PassPhrase 'Set editing password
    .cOption("PDFDisallowCopy") = 0 'Allow copying of contents in PDF
    .cOption("PDFDisallowModifyContents") = 1 'Do not allow modification to PDF
    .cOption("PDFDisallowPrinting") = 0 'Allow pdf to be printed
    .cOption("PDFHighEncryption") = 1 'Enable strong encryption
    .cClearCache 'Clear cache for print job
End With

If Dir(KillFile) <> "" Then 'Deletes existing PDF file with the same name
    SetAttr KillFile, vbNormal
    Kill KillFile
End If

ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut copies:=1, ActivePrinter:="PDFCreator" 'Print entire workbook to PDF

Do Until pdfobj.cCountOfPrintjobs = 1 'Wait until the entire workbook is printed to PDF
    DoEvents 'Wait
Loop

pdfobj.cPrinterStop = False 'Do not stop printer

Do 'Ensure that the file is created before closing PDFCreator
    DoEvents 'Wait
Loop Until Dir(FPath & DefName & ".pdf") = DefName & ".pdf"

pdfobj.cClose 'Ensures that PDFCreator closes
Set pdfobj = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there "PDFCreator" (a version lower than 2) installed on the other computer?

Comment: Please try to replace "this" in the title with more meaningful phrase (One would have to read the body to understand the title otherwise).

Comment: Still alive? Isn't the appropriate PDFCreator version installation the problem? If yes, do you need help to find the appropriate version?

Comment: The other computer is also lower than version 2. Now I see that other computers that will have to use this are version 4. Looks like back to the drawing board. Thanks for pointing me that direction.

Comment: Do you have the installation kit for 2.7.3 version, the last developed before 2? It is not available anymore on their site, I am afraid...

Comment: I'm just going to rewrite it for version 4 and write a new DLL. Then upgrade the other computers. This whole trying to adapt old code new new can be a real pain. Thank you for the help.